# Document to document hyperlink 2007

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I create a link between a Word document and one or more other Word documents in 2007?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click some text and then click **Hyperlink** [image: 1] in the shortcut menu.
2. Under **Link to**, click **Existing File or Web Page**.
3. In the **Look in** box, click the down arrow, and navigate to and select the file that you want to link to.

You can also add a Bookmark to the other document and directly link to that.